# How can I use X.PagedList with ElasticSearch Nest?

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-core, .net-core, pagedlist

**Background**

I'm using ElasticSearch as the search engine for a new ASP.Net Core 2.1 website I'm working on. I'm using the Nest API to integrate with it. I want to use the X.PagedList to handle the paging for me.

I've used this in other ASP.Net Core projects and it's worked well querying data in MS SQL Server.

**Code**

```
ISearchResponse<Foo> searchResponse = 
        _elasticSearchClient.Search<Foo>(s => s
                    .Query(q => q
                        .Bool(b => b.Filter(distanceFilters))
                        )
                    .Source(src => src
                                .Includes(i => i
                                        .Fields(
                                                f => f.Field1,
                                                f => f.Field2,
                                                f => f.Field3
                                                )
                                            )
                            )
                    .From(options.From)
                    .Size(options.Size)
                );

var hitsMD = searchResponse.HitsMetadata;
var results = hitsMD?.Hits.Select(s => new Hit()
{
    Index = s.Index,
    Id = s.Id,
    Score = s.Score,
    Job = s.Source
}
).ToPagedList(PageNumber, PageSize);
```

**Issue**

When I call .ToPagedList on the search results returned by ElasticSearch, it only shows one page of results.

The issue is that ElasticSearch has its own paging mechanism so it's only returning one page of hits.

I had the idea that because ElasticSearch passes back the total number of hits I could tell the PagedList how many items are in the list by setting the PagedList.TotalItemCount property. However, I can't do this as it's a private set.

I've tried removing the from and size but this returns 10 hits which is ElasticSearch's default size which they obviously put in place for performance reasons.

**Question**

How can I make use of the X.PagedList package whilst integrating into ElasticSearch using the Nest API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically got all the pieces here already. All you're missing is `StaticPagedList<T>`. Since paging is *already* being handled by Elasticsearch, you need to simply define a static paging setup, i.e.:

```
var pagedResults = new StaticPagedList<Foo>(results, PageNumber, PageSize, total);
```

Comment: That's great, thank you @Chris Pratt. The paged list pager uses the page number as the part of the querystring. ElasticSearch pages based on From & Size. Is there is a way to render the PagedListPager using From incrementing by size? I could program the From property on my model to calculate based on page*size but I'd rather hook into the From and pass that onto ElasticSearch. Example PagedListPager I'm using. `@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Search", new { page, keywords = options.Keywords, location = options.Location, distance = options.Distance, size = options.Size }))`